# Python Pandas Groupby Alternative (Time Series Analysis)

Tags: python, pandas, ta-lib

Hi guys I'm using pandas to conduct several time series analysis, here is the `sample df`

```
data = {'ticker': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
        'high': [10.2,10.5,11,12,15,16,10.2,5,6,6.2,5.3,5.6,7.8,6],
        'low': [10,10.4,10.5,11,14,15,10,4.8,5.5,6,5,5,7.5,5.8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I wanna compute 5-day beta for these two stocks with `BETA` function in `TA-Lib` and `groupby` in `pandas`, here is my code:

```
def beta(df):
   df['beta'] = talib.BETA(df.high, df.low, timeperiod=5)
   df['beta_above_1'] = np.where(df.beta > float(1), True, False)
return df
df = df.groupby(['ticker']).apply(beta)
```

It works and return me this result:

```
    ticker high  low        beta     beta_above_1
0       A  10.2  10.0       NaN         False
1       A  10.5  10.4       NaN         False
2       A  11.0  10.5       NaN         False
3       A  12.0  11.0       NaN         False
4       A  15.0  14.0       NaN         False
5       A  16.0  15.0  1.151536          True
6       A  10.2  10.0  0.952395         False
7       B   5.0   4.8       NaN         False
8       B   6.0   5.5       NaN         False
9       B   6.2   6.0       NaN         False
10      B   5.3   5.0       NaN         False
11      B   5.6   5.0       NaN         False
12      B   7.8   7.5  1.182857          True
13      B   6.0   5.8  1.177912          True
```

However, the required time is a bit long while I apply this approach to over million rows dataframe. I've researched about **vectorization** to speed up the calculation but I got no idea to improve it.

May I know if there is **other faster ways** to conduct the same analysis? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use [swifter](https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter) for a vectorized `apply()` which is what is slowing you down here, but it doesn't work on `groupby()`. So is it necessary to groupby first?

Comment: @yudhiesh perhaps there are other ways to replace `groupby` to compute beta for every subset (one subset for one ticker). Any suggestion~?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into using Numba - I don't see `groupby()` as being the issue that slows your code down.  Also worth looking at `talib.BETA`  to see if you can re-code it in a vectorised way